# Combining the outputs of multiple models with CTC output layer(ensemble)

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, ctc

I am trying to combine the results of different models to give a better result(like voting in classification).

Output of my models are from ctc layer, which is probability distribution of the output class for time stamp. It has 2d output (T X P) T is the time stamp and P probability Distribution of the output class.

Simple average didn't work as there are some problems with the alignment for different models, ie. Outputs can be _ _ b _ _ and b _ _ _ _ for two models.

Is there a better way to combine the outputs of different models with ctc loss?

Comment: What about geometric instead of arithmetic mean? Combine them within beam search (i.e., work with recombined hypotheses)?

Comment: @Jindřich if we take geometric mean, it won't add up to one right?

Comment: Oh, of course, you're right.